# How to retrieve lifetime operations of a sequence generator using Rx?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reactive

I need way to retrieve all the objects previously generated by a sequence, alongside the new ones, when I'm notified of changes on it, using Rx. I think this is uncommon, since most systems will just want the unprocessed entries, but my situation needs the whole set of values, old and new, to work.

Is it possible to achieve this somehow? I couldn't find any similar examples and no method seem to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Scan` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212007%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for this.

```
IObservable<T> source = ...;
IObservable<List<T>> history = source
    .Scan(new List<T>(), (list, item) => { list.Add(item); return list; });
```

If the `source` emits the tokens `A`, `B`, `C`,
then the `history` emits the tokens `[A]`, `[A B]`, `[A, B, C]` respectively.

If you don't want all emitted values from `history` to be the same `List<T>`, you can slightly modify the call to `Scan`:

```
IObservable<List<T>> history = source
    .Scan(new List<T>(), (list, item) => list.Concat(new[]{ item }).ToList());
```

Comment: How does this actually work? Will the elements be recomputed every time, or are they stored somehow and only copied over (which would be ideal)?

Comment: @julealgon The first argument to `Scan` is the accumulate seed. Call it `list`. Each time the `source` emits an `item`, the lambda `(list, item) => { list.Add(item); return list; })` is called, then the `list` is emitted from `history`. The same `list` will be emitted each time, but each time its length will have increased by `1`. The elements are **not** recomputed every time.

Comment: This is amazing! I can't believe this actually works, just tested it here... I started using Rx yesterday and I can already see how powerful it is.

Comment: @julealgon If you like it, make sure to read through this great introduction: http://introtorx.com/